# Checkpoints not restarted after the point of failure in SSIS

Tags: ssis

I have a package with 1 execute sql task and one DFT. Inside my DFT i am loading data from text file to EMP table.

my text file data has 9 records

```
1, india  
2, pakistan  
3, afgha  
4, Asia  
5,  
6,europe  
7, Australia
```

structure of my table

```
id int not null,  
name varchar not null
```

i have set all the required checkpoint properties for the DFT

```
Checkpoint filename -- Given  
checkpoint usage--ifExists  
save checkpoints -- TRue  
Failpackage on failure-- True
```

now my issue is when i run the package data gets loaded into table for first 4 records , then my package fails, and checkpoint file created. Next time when i restart my package, after making changes to the text file, by replacing null value with some data.

```
5, England
```

instead of loading the data from 5th record, all the records gets loaded into my table. Actually, since i had a failure after 4th record, after restarting my package , i want data from 5th record instead from starting.

Comment: This is the intended behaviour, a checkpoint is just a way to pickup from where the package failed, you need to look into using TransactioOption as well. http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc304421.aspx - Have a look here

Answer (score 0):

Set DFT Transaction option to **Required**